# URL CallBack scheme not valid

Tags: flutter, dart, spotify

I am trying to make an api call to obtain the authentication code for my flutter/dar app. Since I do not have a URL I am using http://localhost:8888/callback this link. I have tried many types of links, changing the AndroidManifest.xml and adding the link to redirect url in spotify developer tools. Currently, it says that the link is not valid and it wont go to the autentication website. What do I need to do for it to work?

Thanks in advance.

```
Future\<void\> \_authorize() async {
   final String authEndpoint ="https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize";
   final String params ="?response_type=code&client_id=$CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=$REDIRECT_URI&scope=$SCOPE";
final String url = authEndpoint + params;

final result = await FlutterWebAuth.authenticate(url: url, callbackUrlScheme: REDIRECT_URI);
print("DONE"); 
final RegExp regExp = RegExp(r"(?<=code=)[^&]*"); 
final String? code = regExp.stringMatch(result);
await _getToken(code!);
```

}
`and this is what I have in manifest`

```
<activity android:name="com.linusu.flutter_web_auth.CallbackActivity">
<intent-filter android:label="flutter_web_auth"> 
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />            
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="localhost"
                android:path="/"
                android:scheme="http" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

`
Currently the code does not pass the FlutterWebAuth and I dont know what to do.